# Чи є різниця між словами "прошу" та "прохаю"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, дієслова

Наткнувся на цей форум, де йшла дискусія про різницю між "прошу" та "прохаю", тому хочу процитувати одного користувача:

> Русизм (**про "я прошу"**), як і "по-моєму", хоча не завжди. З базаром Оверко правий.
>   Просять предмет, прохають про... вчинок? Є щось спільне з благанням. А
>   ось юзати (**тобто вживати**) завжди лише "прошу" - це точно русизм.

А також:

> Я прохаю тебе... Я благаю тебе... - напевно таке забарвлення у цього
>   слова, хоча не зовсім те саме таки.

А от на сайті [Літературне місто](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21533) бачу таку інформацію:

> Обидва слова вживають у нашій мові: перше утворене від дієслова
>   просити (прошу, просиш), друге – від прохати (прохаю, прохаєш). Проте
>   останнім часом дієслово просити в усіх формах вживається значно
>   частіше, ніж прохати, особливо це відчувається в діловому стилі:
>   «прошу надати мені відпустку», «прошу Вашого дозволу», «прошу
>   зарахувати мене слухачем курсів» і т. ін. Частіше вживання дієслова
>   просити відбите і в «Російсько-українському словнику», т. 3. К.,
>   «Наукова думка», 1968, с. 43), де воно стоїть на першому місці серед
>   відповідників до російського слова «просить».

Тобто опираючись на цю інформацію можу зробити висновок, що різниці між словами немає, однак слово "прошу" є популярнішим за "прохаю". СУМ пише, що ці слова [синоніми](http://sum.in.ua/s/prokhaty).

То як бути? Чи є хоч якась різниця між цими словами? Чи все ж вони абсолютні синоніми?

Comment: Слово "прошу" часто і широко слово вживається на Галичині в різних контекстах, так що малоймовірно що це русизм.
- Як аналог "запрошую" - "Прошу до столу",
- Як відповідь на слово "дякую"
- Як прохання до співрозмовника повторити фразу яку не розчув
Так що говорити про синоніми "прошу" і "прохаю" можна тільки в ключі одного з значень слова "прошу".

Answer (score 1):

Слово *просити* точно не є, саме такі терміни красше уживати, росіянізмом чи московізмом, бо [походе](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8#25729) шче від прасловянського *prositi*.

Відмінки теж збіжні з гиншими дійословами, наприклад *носити*: уставною [нормою](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) 1оо є *ношу* і *прошу*, де [польською](https://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=7501&id_znaczenia=0) подібна відміна *прошїчь* (prosić) на *проше* (proszę); для степових [говірок](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CVKiK44moPQJ:www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF/znptdau_2013_2(5)__21.pdf) відповідно *носю* і *просю*. Шчо теж певним чином підтверджує на давність і розповсюдженість слова. Тому тут жодних сумнївів.

Тому красше розглянути як саме утворило ся слово *прохати*.

Спершу можна просто списати на [парабіжність](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8#25304) **х** і **с** для північних прасловянских говірок. Ось приклади [декотрих](http://194.44.152.155/files/Visniki/Ukrain_studia/Ukrain_studia%202001-%203.pdf) [слів](https://movoznavstvo.org.ua/index.php?option=com_attachments&task=download&id=584#page=2): *колисати — колихати, волосатий — волохатий*. В такому разі то просто парабіжні слова. Окремо зазначу, же московська теж має [*прохать*](https://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&method_word=substring&text_word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), котре підписано, так розумію як курське (Слобідщина), але наразі ужив, звісно, ширший. Тому закиди на *просити* удвічі дивнїші.

Можна також зазначити про [протяжність — наворотність](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo), де *прохати* навортне через наростка *ати*, тобто повторювальна дїя. Є шче архаїчна форма [*прошати*](https://archive.org/details/slovn10/page/n165/mode/2up?view=theater) і похідне  від нього, передусїм для північної і значної центральної України, *прашати* через аканя. Порівняйте, де подібні чергуваня: *виносити* — *виношу* — [*виношати*](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/5627-vynoshaty.html), *ходити* — *ходжу* — [*ходжати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/khodzhaty).